# Understanding recursion function call

Tags: c, function, recursion

Where will the value of `n` be stored after first call to factorial()?
When `n=1` then return `1` is sent, why doesn't `res` becomes equal to `1` in main function?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*factorial(n-1); 
}

int main()
{

    int res =factorial(3);
    printf("%d",res) ;
}
```

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you are using. I assume it's C, but it would be better if you cleared that up

Comment: The main point here is the n is a local variable and is given a distinct address each time the function is called.  Each of these instances of n are independent of one another. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run-time stack will have four functions in total: main(), factorial(3), factorial(2), and factorial(1).  Each of these gets its own variable space.  There are *three* instances of the variable **n**, one for each call to **factorial**.

When factorial(1) returns 1, that value isn't returned to main(), because main() is not what called it: factorial(2) called it.  *That* instance performs the operation 2*1 and returns 2.  The caller of that instance is factorial(3), which receives the 2, performs the operation 3*2, and returns a value of 6 to *its* caller, main().

Does that help clear it up?  If not, I have two suggestions:

(1) Search this topic on StackOverflow and the internet in general; there are plenty of detailed walk-through examples of **factorial**.

(2) Insert **print** statements to trace the flow of data and execution.  Within factorial, separate the computation and the return, so you can put a **print** in between:

```
catch = factorial(n-1)
result = n * catch
print n, catch, result
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time a function is called, its parameter and local variables are pushed onto the stack.  In the case of a recursive function, there will be a set of the variables on the stack for *each active invocation of the function*.

In this example, the first call to `factorial` has `n` set to 3.  Within the function, `factorial` is called again, this time with `n` set to 2.  It calls itself one more time with `n` set to 1.  In this last call, it returns a value of 1.  This gets returned to the prior invocation where `n` is 2, which then returns `2 * 1` which is 2.  This value is returned to the first invocation where `n` is 3 and returns `3*2` which is 6 back to `main`.

So the call stack looks like this:

```
main
 |--> factorial(n==3)
        |--> factorial(n==2)
                |--> factorial(n==1)
                     return 1
             return 2*1
      return 3*2
 print 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is not stored in the way of global or static variables - it's stored on the stack. Calling a function with arguments the arguments are being pushed on the stack.

See what's happening when your running your program:

1. `factorial(3)` gets called (in `main`)
2. As `n` is not equal or smaller to 1 `factorial(2)` is called and the result will be multiplied by `n` (is 3).
3. As `n` is not equal or smaller to 1 `factorial(1)` is called and the result will be multiplied by `n` (is 2).
4. As `n` is now equal or smaller to 1 the function returns 1
5. `factorial(2)` returns 1*2
6. `factorial(3)` returns 2*3
7. `res` will be 6